# In Unity3D Physics how can I create an AI that orients to a way point on one axis, then moves to it and stops?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to open by saying this is purely based in physics - no translate or Rotation, because the object programming represents a sailing vessel at sea.

It's already moving over ocean waves through physics, so I wish to avoid breaking
that by using direct control.

My goal is to create a craft that follows a way point system. It targets a point in it's array, rotates toward it on it's world Y axis, and then moves after it's fully oriented.

I have been looking for solutions, but the best I've found thus far apply torque to face towards a target instantly, and I would like more of a slow tank-like rotation. Trying to slow them down produces a weird "ZING!" effect, particularly if the way point suddenly changes to be behind the vehicle.

This is the code I have so far. It sort of produces an effect similar, but it won't stop at the way point and keeps going, creating a strange orbit effect once it passes the target instead of stopping. It's also not directly head-on.

```
    TargetLocation = TempTarget.position;

    Vector3 Heading = TargetLocation - transform.position;
    float direction = Vector3.Dot(Heading, -transform.forward);
    float Distance = Vector3.Distance(TargetLocation, transform.position);

    Debug.Log("Direction Status: " + Mathf.Sign(direction));

    if (Distance > 1.5f)
    {
        // Is the Target in front or behind me? //
        // In Front //
        if (Mathf.Sign(direction) == 1)
        {
            currentThrustPower = 600;
        } else
        {
            currentThrustPower = 0;
        }

        if (direction < 0.55f)
        {
            torquePower = 1400;
        }
        else
        {
            torquePower = 0;
        }

    } else {
        currentThrustPower = 0;
        torquePower = 0;
    }

    RTorque = new Vector3(0, 0, torquePower);
    Vector3 forceToAdd = -transform.up * currentThrustPower;
    boatRB.AddRelativeTorque(RTorque);
    boatRB.AddForceAtPosition(forceToAdd, waterJetTransform.position);
```

Here's an example of what it should be doing:
[image: AI Visual]

Comment: If you want to reduce/cap the rate at which your object rotates due to torque, you could just increase the angular drag of its RigidBody.

Comment: It's not actually rotating correctly towards the waypoint, that's the main problem, not the rate.

Comment: Ah. Well, you're going to need to apply torque in the opposite direction once you start approaching your target facing - even if you stop applying torque, your object will continue spinning due to inertia (in the absence of overwhelming angular drag). To slow down the spinning so it eventually stops, you need to counteract this angular velocity. (How much torque will you need to stop it in time though? That's a physics question you can definitely look up!)